# Mute Button Positioning over Video background

Tags: wordpress, position, html5-video

Have added a mute toggle button to a video background within a Flatsome Banner.

The banner adjusts to screen size to maintain 16:9 proportions for the video.

For desktop, I want the mute button to stay at the bottom left corner of the screen, but only ever *over* the video, and always visible to the user provided the video is on screen.

```
@media (width >= 850px) {
#mutetest {
position: fixed;
bottom: 20px;
left: 20px;
}
}
```

The above achieves the easy part of what I'm seeking, but extends beyond the confines of the video when scrolling down / manipulating the width of the viewport.